# How to check that all entries in a cell array have the same size?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array `C` that whose elements are n-dimensional numeric arrays.  For example:

```
C = {[111 121 131; 211 221 231], ...
     [112 122 132; 212 222 232], ...
     [113 123 133; 213 223 233], ...
     [114 124 134; 214 224 234]};
```

I'm looking for a convenient way to test that they all the nd-arrays in `C` have the same shape (as reported by the `size` function).

The criterion for equality here is not entirely trivial.  Depending on the situation one may want to regard a shape of `[2 3 4]` different from or equal to a shape of, say, `[1 2 3 4]` or `[2 1 3 1 4]`.

For my immediate purposes I want to treat `[2 3 4]` as different from `[1 2 3 4]`, etc.

(BTW: order always matters; e.g., `[2 3 4]` is never equal to `[4 3 2]`, say.)

I tried several things (such as, getting the length of `unique(C)`), but they all fail...  (After almost two years of use, my MATLAB instincts remain close to null.)

Comment: @Dan: I meant "size" as returned by the (poorly-named) `size` function; sorry for the confusion; I've edited my post to make this clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test the size of each cell of `C` against the size of one cell, for example the first. For testing equality of sizes you need [`isequal`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) (`==` won't do because the sizes of the sizes may be different).

```
all(cellfun(@(e) isequal(size(C{1}), size(e)) , C(2:end)))
```

If you want to consider a size `[2 3 4]` equal to `[1 2 3 4]` etc, just add [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html):

```
size1 = size(squeeze(C{1}));
all(cellfun(@(e) isequal(size1, squeeze(size(e))) , C(2:end)))
```

Comment: Thanks; this works for me, but only after I replace the mentions of `C(1)` with `C{1}`.  (BTW this distinction between `X(i)` and `X{i}`, and when to use which, are among the many aspects of MATLAB that, for some reason, never "stick" in my memory.)

Comment: @kjo You're right. Edited. I often get confused with that too!

Answer (score 0):

Don't have matlab here right now, but assuming `C` only has 1 dimension, this might work

```
length(C)==1 || any(cellfun(@(cell)size(cell)~=size(C{1}),C(2:end)));
```

Edit: use `~isequal(size(C{1}),size(cell))` instead of ~=

it's equivalent to

```
function bool=testCell(C)
if length(C) == 1
  bool=1;
  return
end
for i=2:length(C)
  if ~isequal(size(C{1}),size(cell))
    bool=0;
    return 
  end
end
bool=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
length(unique(cellfun('size',C,1)))
length(unique(cellfun('size',C,2)))
```

if both return 1, then all arrays contained by C have the same `size`.

According to `help cellfun`:

CELLFUN('size', C, K) returns the size along the K-th dimension of
    the contents of each cell of C.

Comment: This assumes each cell's content has only two dimensions

Comment: Yes, that's right. But it can be extended easily to a larger dimension by changing the argument K.  Even if your solution is more general, I tried to point out that the OP could use the 'unique' approach he/she already tried.

Comment: But the maximum number of dimensions of the arrays is not known in advance. You would need a previous `cellfun` to determine that

Comment: @LuisMendo It isn't wrong though, it's just sub-optimal.

Comment: @Dan As it stands, I would say it's not wrong, but rather it's incomplete (I haven't downvoted the answer)

Answer (score 0):

One sneaky (and simple) little trick is to `try` something which errors if the sizes don't match, such as concatenation:

```
try
    [C{:}]; %// doesn't catch different size(..,2)
    vertcat(C{:}); %// this does, size(..,1) is already consistent at this point
    samesize = true;
catch e
    samesize = false;
end
```

or recursive `+` (which is a good idea to have anyway, although you might want to implement it in a more robust way):

```
try rplus(C); samesize = true; catch samesize = false; end

function total = rplus(cell)
    if isscalar(cell), total = cell{1};
    else total = cell{1} + rplus(cell(2:end));
    end
end
```